# Change Azure B2C account password on behalf of a user

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to change the password of a user created in my Azure B2C Tenant. I'm using Microsoft.Graph C# SDK to do API calls.

First I create GraphServiceClient by providing details of my tenant:

```
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
   AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
    
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential("tenantId", "clientId",  "clientSecret", options);
    
_client = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
```

Then I use the built-in method of a client to change the user's password:

```
await _client.Users["userId"].ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword).Request().PostAsync();
```

But I get following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
> Message: Access to change password operation is denied.

Is it possible to change the password on behalf of a user? I found conflicting information on this topic on the internet. If this is impossible, what is the valid approach to do this?

I have a SPA frontend app in which the user is authenticated with redirection flow. The access token is then passed to my backend to authorize the requests. Maybe I can use this token to somehow access MS Graph API and change the password?

Note: I would like to let users change their passwords without leaving my SPA application.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried with your code and got same error:

[image]

According to **[MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)**       change password we need **`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`** permission and it only supported for delegated (Work or school accounts).

[image]

Trying to reset the password in the B2C tenant using the Graph API its is not possible Unfortunately, because there is no **`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`**, B2C tenant does not allow this type of password reset. For B2C tenants, the Graph API includes the permission. Only offline access and openID are available as delegated rights in the B2C tenant.

You can reset the password in B2C tenant are either admin performing password reset via Azure Portal or by using [Password Reset Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow) and also refer this [MS-Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709720/index.html) for updating password in powershell and postman.

**Reference:**

["Upn from claims with value null is not a valid upn." - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/246207/34upn-from-claims-with-value-null-is-not-a-valid-u.html) by amanpreetsingh-msft.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the app to create the users as well as reseting their passwords. Following are the only three permissions that were needed on the App Registration.

[image]

Moreover, "Application (client) ID" needs to be added to Authentication Administrator Role.

[image]